# In Santorini, does my opponent win if I pull them onto a third level with the Siren?

Tags: santorini

In Santorini, one of the God Powers is of the Siren. The Siren places a Siren's Song token next to the game board, and on their turn, instead of performing the traditional move+build, can move any of their opponents pawns towards the Siren's Song. If I pull my opponent up onto a third level, do they win, or does it not count as a win for them. Dionysus' power, for example, explicitly states that you cannot cause a win if you move the opponent's piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The win condition is stated as follows:

> If one of your Workers moves up on top of level 3 during your turn, you instantly win!

This doesn't happen in the scenario you described. Your opponent's Worker moved up on top of level 3, but it didn't happen on their turn.